# How do I loop multiple user action in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

Currently I  have issue, when a content get a multiple like from different user, the content will be unable to access due to error (let's say get a likes from 100 different user)

I just manually edit my code below, by changing email address;

```
//new user sign up
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("user.1@gmail.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("name")).sendKeys("New User 1");
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("123456"); 
driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();

//new user like
driver.findElement(By.id("like")).click();

//new user log out
driver.findElement(By.id("logout")).click();
```

How do I automatically loop code above but with new email address?

*(I prefer still using Selenium if possible, because in my Opinion I want to know exact number that trigger the error and control the new user information rather than using stress test tool, and I thought it will be easier to modify for other case such multiple comment, report, feedback, etc)*

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps:

- Create a excel and store all the data's like email, password and
  name.
- Use Apache POI and Dataprovider to read values from excel and pass to the automation scripts.
- Loop through registration process to get work for multiple users with different values in the excel.

(OR)

Follow the methods present in the [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39137689/how-to-generate-1000-unique-email-ids-using-java) to generate random email id's while automation and then loop through each values.

Comment: Actually, a JSON file would be faster, easier to maintain, and not Windows/Excel-dependent.

Comment: I'll try for both method and back for the result

Answer (score 0):

You can just keep your email list in the array like it is shown below:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] emails = new String[]{
          "email1@do.men",
          "email2@do.men",
          "email3@do.men",
          "email4@do.men"
        };

        for(String email: emails){
            //new user sign up
            driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys(email);
            driver.findElement(By.id("name")).sendKeys("New User 1");
            driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("123456");
            driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();
//new user like
            driver.findElement(By.id("like")).click();
//new user log out
            driver.findElement(By.id("logout")).click();
        }
    }
```

However if you do not use any test frameworks like JUnit of TestNg to run your tests you will have to take care of some pre-test and post-test code to be executed (like start browser, close browser, etc.).

Test frameworks also support the mechanisms that can feed each your particular test with a single test entry from your array so that you describe one test and run one time for each of your test data entry.

Take a look at JUnit or TestNg and if you'll have issues with the approach, I'll help you to set up a sample code.